# adding a custom image to make icons in material ui bottom navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a custom image instead of icon in material ui BottomNaviagtion .Does material ui support this ?
Here is the [link to codesandbox for this](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5rzl8qzvy)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass any component(including custom ones that you made).

Here's a simple change I made:

```
<BottomNavigationAction label="Recents" icon={<img src="imageLink"/>} />
```

You can pass you custom image/component instead of `<img src="imageLink"/>`.